# Elastic Beanstalk - 502 error when accesing the webapplication, package.json not found

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed my first web app to the Elastic Beanstalk, but when I try to access it, I get the "502 Bad Gateway" error. In logs, I see this error.

```
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! Linux 4.14.33-51.37.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.13.1-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.13.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /var/app/current/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/app/current/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/app/current/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I did some googling and it seems that this issue occurs when the users zips not only the content of the folder, but also the top-level folder itself. However, this is not my case - I have package.json file in the root of my .zip file, but the system still cannot find it. Does anyone have an idea where could be the problem or how to find the root cause?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just found the core of the problem - the node.js wasnt started automatically by EB. To fix it, I had to create folder ".ebextensions" in the root of the zipped file and in it a file nodecommand.config with the following content

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: NodeCommand
    value: "npm start"
```